# onChange event on a select in Rhomobile's app

Tags: javascript, rhomobile

I am trying to fire an onChange event on a Select, but the event is not being fired.

I have the following code in my select:

```
<select onchange="myEvent()" name="configuration[notifications_enabled]"  id="configuration[notifications_enabled]" data-role="slider"> 
    <option value="0" <%= "selected" if Integer(@configuration.notifications_enabled) == 0 %>>O</option> 
    <option value="1" <%= "selected" if Integer(@configuration.notifications_enabled) == 1 %>>|</option> 
</select>
```

And I have the following event on the top of my file:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function myEvent() { 
    <% app_info("inside the event") %> 
    } 
</script>
```

The message shows up on the console when I first enter the view. But 
when I change the select button it never gets printed again.

I have tried an onClick event instead, but it doesn't work either.

Also I have tried:

```
<script>
  $('#configuration[notifications_enabled]').change(function() 
  {
    app_info('Value change to ' + $(this).attr('value'));
  });
  </script>
```

But nothing happens, not even an error message.

What am I doing wrong?

I am not sure if I can do this on Rhodes, or if I should approach the problem some other way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was solved by calling:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $('.watchable').live('change', function() {

<!-- process you data here or whatever -->

  });
```

where my select tags have a class named watchable